# How to capture SFTP (bash/expect script) error and resend later?

Tags: shell, sftp, expect, file-transfer

I have a bash/expect script that sends files via SFTP (old ssh version). It's done using the bash/expect scripting shown below. The script uses an incoming directory and then after SFTP'ing the file(s), it moves the files into the processed directory.

I've been seeing some failures with some of the files being transferred via SFTP to the GoAnywhere server. I've done some research and it looks like the transfers are failing (about 3% of the time). Error logs on both the SFTP and the GoAnywhere application show the failures, but no detailed information can be found. Perhaps network security, or just a bad network, is cutting the connection.

I've made a lot of advances with the scripting, but I haven't been able to figure out how to capture the error(s) and therefore "not move" the file(s) into the processed directory. I am new to expect scripting. I need some advice on how to rewrite the expects section to capture the error(s) and optionally "mv" (move) command on success.

```
#!/bin/bash
today=`date +'%k:%M:%S-%m.%d.%Y'`
nowdate=`date +'%d%H%M'`
xferhome="/home/me"
recdir="$xferhome/fax_incoming_prod"
procdir="$xferhome/fax_processed_prod"

# log stuff..
logfile="$xferhome/log/fax_xfer_prod.log"
# clean up log file @ beginning of every month..
if [ $nowdate -eq "091200" ]; then
        rm $logfile
fi

cd ${recdir}

# start
{

filearray=($(ls -ltr *.{pdf,fmi} 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $9}'))
idx=$((${#filearray[*]} - 1))

if [ $((${#filearray[*]})) -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "${today} Nothing found.."
    exit 2
fi

echo "${today} - send files..."

for ((i=0;i<=${idx};i++)); do
    echo "SFTP'ing .pdf file: ${filearray[${i}]}"
    fname=${filearray[${i}]}
    export fname
    expect <<'END'

        # Expect Variables

        set FTPUSER MYUser
        set FNAME $env(fname)
        set FTPSERVER secure.site.com

        spawn /usr/bin/sftp -v -oPort=22 $FTPUSER\@$FTPSERVER
        expect "sftp>"
        send "cd /\n"
        expect "sftp>"
        send "put $FNAME\n"
        expect "sftp>"
        send "quit\n"

END
    echo "Moving ${filearray[${i}]} to processed directory"
    mv ${filearray[${i}]} ${procdir}/.
done

# logit all.. :)
} >>$logfile 2>>$logfile
```

Comment: You don't need expect for this. You can pipe commands into sftp, or use `-b batchfile`.  Your script is probably failing because the default timeout for an expect match is 10 seconds.

Comment: I bumped up the timeout to 30 seconds to see if that would help.